# check if username and email already exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, validation, email

I just started with php and i tried to create system to reject "create account" if you type already existing username or password.Thank you,and sorry for my bad english.
**I already tried this.Not working: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460896/check-username-and-email-already-exists-in-php-mysql)**

### This is my php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "itsnikola");

if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lastname']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
    $password2=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password2']);

    if ($password == $password2) {
        session_start();
        $password = ($password);
        $sql="select * from account_info where (username='$username' or email='$email')";

        if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
          if ($username==$row['username'])
          {
              $_SESSION['message'] = "Username je vec registrovan";
          }
          else($email==$row['email']){
              $_SESSION['message'] = "Email je vec registrovan"
          }
       else
        {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, lastname, username, email, password) VALUES('$name' , '$lastname' , '$username' , '$email' , '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Sada si ulogovan";
        $_SESSION['message'] = $username;
        header("location:login.php");
    }else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Ne podudaraju se lozinke!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain exactly what is not working -- error message? not inserted into the database? not detected duplicate? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `session_start()` is called 2 times.
Remove the repeated call inside `if ($password == $password2) {`
You code is also missing a `;` and some `}` (for properly closing your `if` conditions)

**Now the solution:**
Before you can process Database query's result, you need to connect to a DB and execute appropriate SQL command, only then you will get the result you want. Your code is missing this process.

Check my comments in your code below↓ and then check again in corrected code

```
if ($password == $password2) {
        session_start(); // remove this repeated call
        $password = ($password);
        $sql="select * from account_info where (username='$username' or email='$email')";
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) { // $res isn't defined
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
          if ($username==$row['username'])
          {
              $_SESSION['message'] = "Username je vec registrovan";
          }
          else($email==$row['email']){  // `else` doesn't work this way, use `elseif`
              $_SESSION['message'] = "Email je vec registrovan"  // ; missing
          }
```

*Corrected Code*:

```
if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
    $name      = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
    $lastname  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lastname']);
    $username  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email     = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
    $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password2']);

    if ($password == $password2) {
        $password = ($password);
        $sql      = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$username' OR email='$email')";
        $res      = mysqli_query($db, $sql); // you were calling $res but it wasn't defined; this connects to the DB and executes SQL and then assigns the result
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            if ($username == $row['username']) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Username je vec registrovan";
            } elseif ($email == $row['email']) {  // changed `else` to `elseif` to include the condition, `else` doesn't accept conditional checks
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Email je vec registrovan";  // added ;
            }
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, lastname, username, email, password) VALUES ('$name', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
            if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
                // New record inserted
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Sada si ulogovan";
                $_SESSION['message'] = $username;
                header("location: login.php");
            } else {
                echo("Error: " . mysqli_error($db));
            }
        }
    } // required to close the password checking condition
    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Ne podudaraju se lozinke!";
    }
}
```

> **Suggestions:**
>
> 1. Use prepared statement instead of directly passing user provided input into SQL
>    (critical, your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection)
> 2. Use an IDE that supports PHP and offers syntax highlighting (Atom, Visual Studio Code, PhpStorm etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the very important line here before this line `if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)`

```
$sql="select * from account_info where username='$username' or email='$email' ";

$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql); // you're missing this line to query by $sql 

if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
// you're other code goes here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this

```
<?php
session_start();

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "itsnikola");
if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
    $name      = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
    $lastname  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lastname']);
    $username  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email     = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
    $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password2']);

    if ($password == $password2) {
        $password = ($password);
        $sql      = "select * from account_info where (username='$username' or email='$email')";
        $res      = mysqli_query($db, $sql); // you were calling $res but it wasn't defined; this connects to the DB and executes SQL and then assigns the result
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            if ($username == $row['username']) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Username je vec registrovan";
            } elseif ($email == $row['email']) {  // changed `else` to `elseif` to include the condition, `else` doesn't accept conditional checks
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Email je vec registrovan";  // added ;
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, lastname, username, email, password) VALUES('$name' , '$lastname' , '$username' , '$email' , '$password')";
                mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Sada si ulogovan";
                $_SESSION['message'] = $username;
                header("location:login.php");
            }
        } // required to close `if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)`
    } // required to close the password checking condition
    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Ne podudaraju se lozinke!";
    }
}
?>
```

But not working Error code:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in Z:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\register.php on line 17